# how to execute php code on every time load website on laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have dynamic menu on header which i get its content form database, so i want to know **WHERE & HOW** can implement code to get data form database to be defined on whole web application? without need to put code on each class responsible for load view.

```
$categuries_list = DB::table('categories')
                            ->where('parent', '=', 2)
                            ->lists('name', 'id');
```

I think to cache what i need but on this case i will put code on each class load view(so that is bad solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what view composers are for.

```
View::composer('header', function($view)
{
    $categuries_list = DB::table('categories')
        ->where('parent', '=', 2)
        ->lists('name', 'id');

    $view->with('categuries_list', $categuries_list);
});
```

Just swap out the `header` with the actual name of the view which contains the header.

This code can go anywhere which is being autoloaded.

Can read about view composers in the documentation. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers